# How to have Autofac inject properties upon loading a web forms page in an iframe with Server.Transfer?

Tags: c#, webforms, autofac

EDIT: It *does* work when the page is retrieved by a Request.Redirect(), the problem is appearing when the iframe is navigated with Server.Transfer(). Preferably I'd like to not just ad hoc change every reference to Server.Transfer() in the application to Response.Redirect(), since I don't know that they are truly interchangeable

I am working with a legacy web forms application with a lot of global variables, god classes, etc and the first thing I've been trying to improve in it is factoring out some methods into specific classes/interfaces and adding dependency injection alongside that. This app mostly works by loading in a Main.aspx page which contains an iframe that loads subsequent pages. I have found that the injection doesn't happen when the page is loaded within the iframe even though it works fine externally.

Every page, including Main.aspx, derives from a "ProjectBasePage" although that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Main.aspx:

```
<iframe id="webservername" src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:0px;height:13px;width:50px;vertical-align:bottom;"></iframe>
```

Overview.aspx.cs

```
[InjectProperties]
public partial class Overview : ProjectBasePage
{
    public ITableRepository TableRepo { get; set; }
```

Global.asax

```
static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

        public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
        {
            get { return _containerProvider; }
        }

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<TableRepository>().As<ITableRepository>();

            _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
        }
```

And that's really about it, nothing complex at all. It works fine if I manually "inject" in Page_Load or by setting the property myself, I just don't know where Autofac is tripping up because of the iframe loading and I don't have enough experience with it. I'd love to just convert the iframe to a Master Page or something instead but that's a bit more work than I can take on myself at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Autofac is aware of the issue and won't fix.

https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/337

The work around is to simply use the Manual Injection procedure:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#manual-property-injection